# Returning duplicates within a given window size in an array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I saw this question and I have no idea how to do the second part given the time and space constraints:

Given an array of values, design and code an algorithm that returns whether there are two duplicates within k indices of each other? k indices and within plus or minus l (value) of each other? Do all, even the latter, in O(n) running time and O(k) space.

It seems impossible to me to know whether there is a duplicate of a given value within a window size of the value without looking at all values with index difference between k and a[i] but since a[i] might be large, I think that would take O(n^2). Can it be done in O(n)?

Answer (score -2):

This sounds suspiciously like home work. Yes, it can be done in O(n) time and O(k) space. Hint: You need two data structures, and one of them is a hash map.

Comment: Hint2: you can combine the LRU with the hash table.

Comment: Is this for both the first and second part of the question or just the first part. I think in the second part, the value of k is basically dynamic- you don't know because it's based on the values in the array (you check with a window size of k AND with a window size of the current value that you're trying to find a duplicate for- that's the part I'm having trouble with but I did the first part with a hash map)